# SQL Server 2016 Source Control

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, azure-devops

Anyone know where I can find the 'Source Control' option under tools for SQL Server 2016? I'm looking to integrate Visual Studio Team Services (was TFS Online) with SQL Server 2016.

As you can see, this is [SQL Server 2012](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVGch.png) and this is [SQL Server 2016](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3cnj.png).

Any Ideas?

Comment: I think what you want is a SQL Server Data Tools project in Visual Studio (also available as independent download with VS Shell). Then you source control your SSDT project just like any other Visual Studio project.

Comment: @crowcoder sure and you have source control integration with other tools also but point is, SSMS had this capability in the past. It was a useful feature that many of us have depended on. Removing it without informing users is not nice. Alternative tools are often non-starters. Moving stuff and retraining/relearning aside, not everyone can install whatever tool they find useful as they please. Many companies have very strict software policies where even DBAs are not admins/power users on their own workstations - admin accounts are high value targets for bad guys.

Comment: @SQLmojoe, its just a suggestion, hence comment, not answer. If SSMS got installed then there is reason to hope that SSDT may have a chance as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Source Control integration in SQL Server Management Studio is being deprecated. Please refer to this link for details:
[Deprecated Database Engine Features in SQL Server 2016](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx)

> Category - Deprecated feature
>
> SQL Server Management Studio - Solution Explorer integration in SQL
>   Server Management Studio  & Source Control integration in SQL Server Management Studio"

Comment: I cannot even begin to fathom the reasoning that led to this decision.

Comment: The source control option is deprecated, but it is only a hidden feature, that can be restored.

Answer (score 2):

To restore the "Source Control" option in SQL Server Management Studio, you have to edit the file
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL\Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\ssms.pkgundef`
**SQL Server Management Studio 2016**
 

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\ssms.pkgundef`
**SQL Server Management Studio 2017**

Inside this file, you have to comment out the complete block called
 
`//TFS SCC Configuration entries. The TFS entries block Team Explorer from loading.`



in this [Link](http://h-savran.blogspot.co.at/2017/08/enable-tfs-and-git-source-control.html) you can find the full description, how to restore the "Source Control" option in SQL Server Management Studio 2016 and SQL Server Management Studio 2017.

Comment: Everytime you do an SSMS upgrade you have to comment these out. As SQL SSMS 2017 just did one for me and broke these changes.

Also you may get another prompt when trying to browse Source Control explorer. What worked for me is:

Disabling all settings under - TFS SCC Configuration

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft appears to be trying to force everything into Visual Studio. Visual Studio is a 'push only' model as far as I can tell.
By that I mean everything flows from Visual Studio to SQL Server, their appears to be no easy way to do the reverse.
This makes the model un-acceptable for use in a mixed mode environment where some developers use Visual Studio and some use SSMS.
After the initial project load from SQL Server there appears to be no way that is built into VS to bring the SQL Server code from SQL Server into VS without a cumbersome method of replacing the file. When you use this method all of your tracking history is gone.
This is un-acceptable for our purposes.

Comment: This statement is not true. In VS SQL Server Database Projects you can compare and update the two schema in any direction. Just right click on the project, `Compare Schema`, configure the source and destination, configure the comparison and do it. You can update existing files in VS using the source from SQL Server (or create files for new objects). You can save the whole schema compare config and reuse it. (You can compare to other project, SQL Server database and dacpac files)